# Searching for {time} in a message template, without having the workbook parse it as a parameter

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I want to create an azure monitor workbook that lets me search for specific message templates. Usually, these message templates contain placeholders. For example:

```
logger.LogInformation("Finished executing, took {time}ms", time);
```

Problem is though, if I include the placeholder in the query string for a workbook, it will fail since it considers the placeholder a parameter for the workbook. A very small example can be seen underneath.

```
AppTraces 
| where Properties.MessageTemplate == 'Finished executing, took {time}ms'
```

This will give me the following error message:

```
This query could not run because some parameters are not set.
Please set: time
```

I can't seem to figure out how to escape these characters, since this is not actually related to the kusto language, but more of an issue with the workbook. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't (yet) have an escape sequence for parameters in workbooks.

As a workaround, what you can do is split it up so workbooks doesn't *detect* it as a parameter, something like `strcat('Finished executing, took {', 'time}ms'`

Comment: there are other various workarounds, if this is ALWAYS the word time, like making a hidden text parameter named `time` that has the string value `{time}`, so that the parameter replacement just puts the value back in

Comment: You mention yet - is this something that is in the works? Do you have a developer feedback channel like visual studio has where I can add my voice? As a side note, while I am not a super fan of either solutions, I kinda like the one you came with in the comment better - would you mind adding it to the approved answer?

Comment: the general case hasn't come up enough to need an "escape" sequence and even then there hasn't been good consensus of what that behavior *should* be because usually it comes up as cases where it is static text that nobody wants to modify to add the escapes to?  If there *were* to be an escape, what would you expect?  for example, ARM templates also allow param-like things using `[something]` but their requirement is the string had to *start* with `[` or they dont look any further, and then you escape with `[[` (which is strange since their format is json so you have to escape arrays?)

Comment: I kinda agree - I would much rather NOT add escape characters, as I am usually (I think always?) searching for static text. Wouldn't the best solution be to do something like a string literal, like c#? So, the where query would be something like where Properties.MessageTemplate == @"Finished executing, took {time}ms".

Comment: (in this *specific* case, @ is a language feature of the underlying database as well, so we can't do that or some queries that normally work in that language would not work)